# git lfs ls-files : Asterisk (*) vs. Dash (-)

Tags: git, git-lfs

This is my listing of git lfs managed files

`$ git lfs ls-files`

```
b1d5dd29dd - file1.zip
27d3073f43 - file2.zip
fb4e699c05 * file3.zip
```

**Why does one file have an asterisk/star (*) beside it, while the others have a dash (-) beside them?**

The git lfs wiki seems to indicates that (*) is expected.

https://github.com/github/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial

`git lfs status` shows all clear (nothing to be committed/pushed/staged).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This wasn't documented in [the ls-files man page](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-ls-files.1.ronn), so [I dug into the source code to find the answer](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/8f90f594162d0a7e90e2f5785287f4327f097235/commands/command_ls_files.go#L50).

```
func lsFilesMarker(p *lfs.WrappedPointer) string {
    info, err := os.Stat(p.Name)
    if err == nil && info.Size() == p.Size {
        return "*"
    }

    return "-"
}
```

`*` *probably* means the file on disk is the same size as the one in the repository or index, depends on what's in `WrappedPointer.Size`. [It was added in this commit, but not explained](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/commit/2082b26ce728bb8a960b28bcac9aaecbb6a251c1). Either way, it seems like a poor test as the content can change but not the size.

Note that [the `-` code path is never tested](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/blob/8f90f594162d0a7e90e2f5785287f4327f097235/test/test-ls-files.sh). You might wish to [let them know](https://github.com/github/git-lfs/issues/new) about the lack of tests and docs.

Comment: Based on the 4th line of the commit message, I would guess that the '*' indicates that the file is a LFS pointer, and a '-' indicates that the file is a full object.  But again, that's just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

This [page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/git-lfs-ls-files.1.html#:%7E:text=Display%20paths%20of%20Git%20LFS,minus%20(%2D)%20a%20full%20object.) suggests:

> An asterisk (*) after the OID indicates a LFS pointer, a minus (-) a full object.

But my experience has been the opposite.

For me, the minus (-) indicated a pointer and the asterisk (*) indicated the real large-file in git lfs.

Comment: The error in the docs seems to be fixed now "An asterisk (*) after the OID indicates a full object, a minus (-) indicates an LFS pointer." Commit that fixed that: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/commit/8c53b912e56cffa5644a976908fa7a0ece14943d

Answer (score 1):

Just like in git, the '-' indicates that the file has been deleted in the working directory. The two files with '-' had indeed been inadvertently deleted. Restoring them brought back the '*'.

What threw me off was that `git lfs status` reported nothing, but I guess I'm interpreting it wrong.